# Are there any way to get images src from Tumblr Post?

Tags: tumblr

Are there any way to get images src from Tumblr Post?

I want to get images Src to display on my website avi API....

Ex:

I have URL POST :
http://ronaldonunsevgilisiyim.tumblr.com/post/84606560257

And Images Src of this Post:
http://24.media.tumblr.com/d4e9175ce6ee59f284638125ed33fca4/tumblr_n4zx1xQnbt1tac4yno1_500.gif

Thank you very much !

Comment: Get the post by `id` (http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posts) and then get its `photos` (http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#photo-posts)?

Answer (score -2):

What are you using for your website if your programming your own using html css then you should do this

```
<img src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/d4e9175ce6ee59f284638125ed33fca4/tumblr_n4zx1xQnbt1tac4yno1_500.gif"></img>
```

and to do this on wordpress go [Here](http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/how-do-you-add-html-codes)
will show you how to add this code to the wordpress post

Comment: Thanks @Marley Plant. But i want to use PHP auto get URL of images.